# VueJS - How to check the truthiness of an object of objects for a v-if

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js, truthiness

I have this appointments object that has three keyed arrays. I'm trying to find a clean JS way to check the truthiness for a v-if when all three block arrays are empty a la:

```
{ 
    "block_1": [], 
    "block_2": [], 
    "block_3": [] 
}
```

I have been trying to use `Object.values()`. For example, this code will return true if all the arrays are truthy and false if even one of them is empty:

```
Object.values(appointments).every(item => item.length)
```

Comment: `block_1.length === 0 && block_2.length === 0 && block_3.length === 0`? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Just conditionally render a button. Yeah, I thought of that. I was just curious if someone knew of a slicker way.

Comment: Slightly shorter: `block_1.length + block_2.length + block_3.length === 0`

Comment: Thanks! That works pretty well. Sometimes there just isn't a slick way 

Comment: *if all the arrays are truthy* Arrays are always truthy when coerced to a Boolean value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a computed property:

```
hasAppointment() {
  return !!Object.values(this.appointments).find(i => i.length);
}
```

And then use that computed in your `v-if` statement:

```
<div v-if="hasAppointment"></div>
```

Comment: That is always returning false.

Comment: It shouldn't be. Although I made some small assumptions about your Vue component since you didn't share it. [Here's a full fiddle example.](https://jsfiddle.net/rcg61fLv/1/)

Comment: Yeah, that totally works right. The issue is that when the data comes in it's an object of objects, rather than an object of arrays: `{ block_1: {"foo": "foo"}, block_2: [], block_3: [] }`

Comment: So... this works: `return !!Object.values(this.appointments).find(i => Object.keys(i).length)`. Anyways, thanks! My bad for leaving that part out.

Comment: Is there a reason that you initialize the data as arrays? Because if not, you should just initialize them to `null` and you could use `.find(i => i)` instead.

Comment: It's some weird old-school dev's backend php stuff that I cannot change at the moment, so I'm just working with it the best I can. It's totally necessary. Could've just been json. The block numbers are in the nested objects. He just likes to key everything extraneously.